# Fit image in UIImageView using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm facing a really weird problem with UIImageView, I was trying to set an image - which created by take the screenshot of the current view - to an ImageView with content mode is UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

It worked fine when I set the image by the interface builder in the xib file or when I set the image created by [UIImage imageNamed:]. They both worked fine with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

But when I take the snap shot of a view and set the image to the image view, the image did not fit to the UIImageView. I've tried all the solutions I found on here like .ClipsToBound = YES but they didn't work at all. I'm really confused by now.

Here's the code when I take the screen shot and create the UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotWithRect:(CGRect)captureRect
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    UIImage *screenshot;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, scale);
    CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureRect);
    {
        if(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext is nil. You may have a UIView (%@) with no really frame (%@)", [self class], NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
        }
        else
        {
            [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

            screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenshot;
}
```

And when I set the image to the image view

```
UIImage* snap = [[UIImage alloc] init];
// start snap shot
UIView* superView = [self.view superview];
CGRect cutRect = [superView convertRect:self.cutView.frame fromView:_viewToCut];
snap = [superView screenshotWithRect:cutRect];
[self.view addSubview:self.editCutFrameView];
// end snap shot -> show edit view
[self.editCutFrameView setImage:snap];
```

Here's a picture compare the 2 results:
[image]

Many thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**: As @Saheb Roy mentioned about the size, I checked the image size and it's about 400x500px and the thumbnail.png's size is 512x512px so I think it's not about the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the second case, the snapshot image is itself **exactly that size as you can see**. Hence the image is not being stretched or fitted accordingly. 
Earlier images are fitting to screen accordingly as the images were bigger than the `imageview` but with different ratio or same than that of the image.

But the one where it is not fitting to the `imageview`, the image itself is of that much size, i.e. smaller than that of the imageview, hence it is NOT being fitted to the bounds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I checked the image it's not that small, and if it really was a small size image then it should be at the center of the image view. But as you can see, it was not at the center.

Comment: plz reply with the size of the imageview and the size of the image